# The mathematics of method of moments estimation

Tags: statistics

I have a test in statistics coming up and I've stumbled upon this exact question several times in different formats. I know what to do, I just can't get the maths right.

"The stochastic variable ${X}$ has a skewness in its exponential distribution, that is, its density function is ${f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(x-a)}}$ for ${x ≥ a}$ (and ${0}$ otherwise). You have access to ${n}$ independent outcomes ${x_1,...,x_n}$ of ${X}$. Determine the "method of moments" estimation of ${a}$ and ${\lambda}$"

So really my question is about how ${\int_{a}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x) \ dx = a + \dfrac{1}{\lambda}}$

and

${\int_{a}^{\infty} x^2 \cdot f(x) \ dx = a^2 + \dfrac{2a}{\lambda} + \dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}}$

I get that this might be elementary but I can't get it right. All the help I can get is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you mean 'shifted' instead of 'skewed'.

I'll get you started with the expectation: Let $Y = X - a$. So that $Y$ is an unshifted exponential with $E(Y) = \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\, dy$, which can be found to be $1/\lambda$ upon integrating by parts. Then $E(X) = a + 1/\lambda.$  I'll leave $E(X^2)$ to you.

Then, to find method of moments estimators (MMEs) you set $\bar X = \tilde a + 1/\tilde{\lambda}$, and similarly $(\sum X,^2)/n = \tilde a^2 + 2 \tilde a/{\tilde \lambda} + 2/{\tilde{\lambda^2}}.$
Then solve these two simultaneous equations to get the MMEs $\tilde a$
and $\tilde \lambda$ or $a$ and $\lambda$, respectively.

Note: Some students get the idea that MMEs are unbiased because they are based on means, etc. But expectation is a linear operator and so does not "survive" nonlinear arithmetic such as taking reciprocals. For
example, $E(1/{\tilde \lambda}) \ne 1/E(\tilde \lambda),$ so $\tilde \lambda$ a biased estimate of $\lambda.$

Comment: yes "shifted" would be a better word, haha I knew i messed up the translation on that one. Nice! thanks for the help!

Comment: Both _shifted_ and _skewed_ are have technical meanings in stat/prob. (I know about 100 words of Swedish and none of them technical.)

Comment: the thing is, whatever foreign language it's only the swearwords that matter!!